# XElement with LINQ Select and optional elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to display some date from some XML I get from an external service. I am using XElement and I try to use LINQ select to get my data.

```
var xElem = XElement.Load(HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(url));
var books = (from pubs in xElem.Elements("result")
             select new
             {
                 Id = (string)pubs.Element("data").Element("id"),
                 Title = (string)pubs.Element("data").Element("title"),
                 Year = (string)pubs.Element("data").Element("year"),
                 Resources = (string)pubs.Element("data")
                                         .Element("resource")
                                         .Element("url")
                                         .ElementValueNull(),
                 Authors= pubs.Element("data").Elements("person")
             }).ToList();
foreach (var book in books)
{
    // Put the string together with string builder....
    foreach (var person in book.Authors)
    {
        //Get the authors
    }
}
```

And of course I have made the class for ElementValueNull.

```
//This method is to handle if element is missing
public static string ElementValueNull(this XElement element)
{
    if (element != null)
        return element.Value;

    return "";
}

//This method is to handle if attribute is missing
public static string AttributeValueNull(this XElement element, string attributeName)
{
    if (element == null)
        return "";
    else
    {
        XAttribute attr = element.Attribute(attributeName);
        return attr == null ? "" : attr.Value;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the resource tag with it's elements are not always present. And if it isn't there it will skip the whole record. Is there any easy way of making it so that it will just make the Resources have the empty string returned from my class but still add the record still using a LINQ select?

EDIT with XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tester xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://tester.no/xmlSchema/xsd/tester.xsd">
  <generert>2014-12-01</generert>
  <result>
    <data>
      <id>297474</id>
      <person>
        <id>11690</id>
        <surname>Medel-Svensson</surname>
        <firstname>Ronnie</firstname>
      </person>
      <title>Title 1</title>
      <year>2009</year>
    </data>
  </result>
  <result>
    <data>
      <id>807059</id>
      <person>
        <id>11690</id>
        <surname>Bronskimlet</surname>
        <firstname>Hallstein</firstname>
      </person>
      <person>
        <id>328009</id>
        <surname>Kroksleiven</surname>
        <firstname>Jostein</firstname>
      </person>
      <person>
        <id>328010</id>
        <surname>Gassolini</surname>
        <firstname>Ruffino</firstname>
      </person>
      <person>
        <id>327990</id>
        <surname>von Schnellfahrer</surname>
        <firstname>Heinrich</firstname>
      </person>
      <title>Title 2</title>
      <year>2010</year>
      <resource>
        <type>
          <code>TEXT</code>
        </type>
        <url>http://www.example.com/</url>
      </resource>
    </data>
  </result>
  <result>
    <data>
      <id>1164653</id>
      <person>
        <id>11690</id>
        <surname>Bergsprekken</surname>
        <firstname>Mysil</firstname>
      </person>
      <title>Title 3</title>
      <year>2014</year>
      <resource>
        <type>
          <code>FULLTEKST</code>
        </type>
        <url>http://www.example.com/</url>
      </resource>
    </data>
  </result>
</tester>
```

Comment: You could use `XPath` in order to extract the data fast and easy, but you should show us the format of the XML.

Comment: Yeah I could of course use XPath, but I wanted to try this using LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

- if you use `Element(..)`, then the result could be `null`.  This may cause null reference exceptions if elements are missing in your path.  A more elegant way to handle this would be to use sequences and return an element if present using `SingleOrDefault()`
- Both `XElement` and `XAttribute` have a bunch of explicit type conversion operators built in.  This means you can cast to `string` and various other primitives.  As string is a reference type, it would return `null` if the `XObject` was null.  Value types such as `int` would throw an exception in this case, though `int?` would not.

With this in mind, something like this should solve your problem.  Note as 'data' is common to all, you can put this in the initial selector:

```
from pubs in xElem.Elements("result").Elements("data")
select new
{
    Id = (string)pubs.Element("id"),
    Title = (string)pubs.Element("title"),
    Year = (string)pubs.Element("year"),
    Resources = (string)pubs.Elements("resource")
                            .Elements("url")
                            .SingleOrDefault(),
    Authors= pubs.Elements("person")
}
```

Comment: Cheers Charles. I put in the data in the path before the select and it looks cleaner. However trying your code with use of SingleOrDefault still only return 2 records out of the total of 3 that I am trying. Leaving out the record without the resource.

Comment: Could you maybe include a sample of the xml you're parsing?  Though I think I may have simplified the `XLinq` code, I think the issue of 'skipping' a whole `data` element may be unrelated to the code you tried originally.  If it had been attempting to parse a `data` element missing a `resource`, it should have thrown an exception rather than 'skipping' it.

Comment: Added the XML example now.

Comment: OK, I've loaded the xml via `XElement.Load`.  With your code, I get a null reference exception (as I'd expect), and with my code I get 3 items, one of which has Resources as `null`.   There's no reason you should get 2.

Comment: Sorry Charles, I must have messed up something on my side here afte the original post. I started fresh using your example with the SingleOrDefault and it all seem to work like a charm! Thanks a bunch! :D